# iOS6 displaying site too large when using initial-scale=1.0 and maximum-scale-1.0

Tags: html, responsive-design, viewport

When I remove initial and maximum-scale out from the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

tag, iOS 6 Safari is diplaying the site too large. I have to take the initial and maximum out for it too fit correctly. Is it acceptable to leave the viewport tag like this? I haven't tested on other mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following for ensure proper sizing on all mobile devices:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

In some cases, I will adjust the initial-scale down a minor amount to ensure the proper scale:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.96"> // Scale as needed
```